# Check if a word in present in multiple sheets

Tags: python, pandas, nlp

I have a data frame in the following format:

Sample dataframe:

```
row1:['efcc', 'fficial', 'billiontwits', 'since', 'covid', 'landed']
row2:['when', 'people', 'say', 'the', 'fatality', 'rate', 'of', 'coronavirus', 'is']
row3:['in', 'the', 'coronavirus-induced', 'crisis', 'people', 'are',  'cyvbwx']
row4:['in', 'the', 'be-induced', 'crisis', 'people', 'are',  'cyvbwx']
```

columns2(sheet_retreived_from) has list of place the word is from:

```
row1:sheet1
row2:sheet2
row3:sheet3
row4:sheet2
```

And a words_collection which has list of words through below code:

```
words_collection=[]
for w in sample.tokenised_text:
   for t in w:
       words_collection.append(t)
```

and sheet names from: `sheetlist=list(set(sample.sheet.to_list()))`

However, struggling to find a proper way to iterate over the dataframe to check if a word is present in more than one sheet?

Basically I'm looking for output which shows:

[image: Sample_output]

Comment: Dont post your data as images. Copy past it in question.

Comment: Please update the question to show what you've tried / researched so far; then where you are stuck.

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


df = pd.DataFrame({'sheet':['sheet1', 'sheet2', 'sheet3', 'sheet2'],
    'tokenized_text':[['efcc', 'fficial', 'billiontwits', 'since', 'covid', 'landed'], ['when', 'people', 'say', 'the', 'fatality', 'rate', 'of', 'coronavirus', 'is'], ['in', 'the', 'coronavirus-induced', 'crisis', 'people', 'are',  'cyvbwx'], ['in', 'the', 'be-induced', 'crisis', 'people', 'are',  'cyvbwx']] })

words_collection = ['efcc','fficial','billiontwits','since','covid','landed','in']

# Create a dictionary that maps each sheet to the words it contains
sheets_words = {}

# Go over the rows of the dataframe, and concatenate for each sheet the words in it
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    sheet_id = row['sheet']
    if sheet_id not in sheets_words.keys():
        sheets_words[sheet_id] = set()
    sheets_words[sheet_id] |= set(row['tokenized_text'])

# Create a dictionary that maps for each word from `words_collection` the number of sheets it appears at
word_to_number_of_sheets = { w : 0 for w in words_collection }

# Go over the sheets
for sheet_id, sheet_words in sheets_words.items():
    # For each word in words_collection
    for w in words_collection:
        # Add 1 to the sheet it appears in if it appears in current sheet
        if w in sheet_words:
            word_to_number_of_sheets[w] += 1

word_to_number_of_sheets_as_list = [(k,v) for k,v in word_to_number_of_sheets.items()]

# [('efcc', 1), ('fficial', 1), ('billiontwits', 1), ('since', 1), ('covid', 1), ('landed', 1), ('in', 2)]
print(word_to_number_of_sheets_as_list)
```

Comment: @suraj Looking again at your question I deduce you want a list of tuples, so updated accordingly